# Задержка скролла окна браузера при помощи JS

Tags: javascript

Как заставить окно браузера прокрутиться с задержкой на несколько секунд после открытия? Я могу сделать анимацию с помощью CSS (transition), я могу сделать прокрутку сразу на необходимое количество пикселей в JS (функция – метод scrollTo). Но я не понимаю как можно эту функцию на JS прокрутить с задержкой, например 10s. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```js
function winScrollTo() {
    window.scrollTo({
        top: 1000,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
    });
}
winScrollTo();
```

Вот в результате этого фрагмента кода при открытии страницы она сразу прокручивается. Но как сделать задержку на 10 секунд? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Именно на JS

Comment: [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [setTimeout](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval):

```
function winScrollTo() {
    window.scrollTo({
        top: 1000,
        left: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
    });
}

setTimeout(winScrollTo, 10000); //1 секунда = 1000 мс
```